# Why document.getElementById.style and $.css behave differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering that the `onclick` method that is calling my function doesn't have access to the style value on the first click but it does on the second. I was wondering if for jQuery it would be the same but it seems like it's not.
I created a short code that shows the issue:

HTML:

```
<p class="flip" onclick="myFunction()">Click to show panel</p>

<div id="panel">
  <p>panel</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#panel, .flip {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #a6d8a8;
  margin: auto;
}

.flip {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#panel {
  display: none;
}
```

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("panel").style.display); //on first call returns empty string
  console.log($("#panel").css("display")); // on first call returns none
  const setPanel = (a) => {document.getElementById("panel").style.display = a;};
  const getPanel = document.getElementById("panel").style.display;
    (getPanel === "none") ? setPanel("block") : setPanel("none");
}
```

I am wondering why the behavior is the way it is and is it possible to retrieve the style directly without using jQuery?

Comment: The jQuery `.css()` API looks at the element `style` object but also at CSS rules by using other browser APIs. The `style` object on an element only contains rules set directly on the element via the HTML "style" attribute. Layout rules from CSS are not directly available on the `style` object.

Comment: what @Pointy said. `element.style` refers to the style property of the element, not those applied by stylesheets. If you need the latter, use `window.getComputedStyle(element)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery internally uses `.getComputedStyle()` to determine the effective styles on an element rather than the ones explicitly defined on that element. `.style` only returns the explicit ones.

Observe:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("panel")).display); //on first call returns none
  console.log($("#panel").css("display")); // on first call returns none
  const setPanel = (a) => {document.getElementById("panel").style.display = a;};
  const getPanel = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("panel")).display;
    (getPanel === "none") ? setPanel("block") : setPanel("none");
}
```

```css
#panel, .flip {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #a6d8a8;
  margin: auto;
}

.flip {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#panel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="flip" onclick="myFunction()">Click to show panel</p>

<div id="panel">
  <p>panel</p>

</div>
```